# Configure nginx to proxy pass when some conditions occurs or to use php fastcgi otherwise

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have a particular case on which I want to redirect visitors to a "prerender" server when I found out the visitor is a crawler (to give a SEO-optimised website) and to a standard php fast-cgi instance (trough fastcgi pass) otherwise.

My experience with nginx is very scarce so I was not able to accomplish what I needed to.

Here's a draft of my current configuration

```
server {
    server_name example.com;  

    root  /vagrant/example.com/web;
    index app.php;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share;
        index index.php;
        location ~* \.php {
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    } 

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {

        #if $prerender is 1 should use the prerender proxy

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|pinterest|vkshare|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic XXXXXXXXXXX"; #prerender server needs authentication
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if ($prerender = 1) {
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3456;
            break;
        }

        #otherwise should use the fastcgi proxy

        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Notice that in my dev environment I also have a location block to enable phpmyadmin.
The previous configuration does not work as intended because it always uses the fastcgi_pass.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the nested locations, plus, your nested locations are of different type - one is simple and one is regexp-based. Regexp-based locations have higher priority. Furthermore, on a 0 nesting level you have one simple location and one regexp-based location too. This is overcomplicated, thus it doesn't work. Try to simplify your config. Start with avoiding nested locations, for example. Being simple is a winning strategy.

Comment: If you are referring to the phpmyadmin configuration block, it's not the main topic here. I can even strip it out for now. The real problem is about choosing prerender or default php files as of the block `location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$)`... Any idea on this?

Comment: It seems that just by moving the phpmyadmin block to the end of the config file it fixed the problem!